# How to track network usage in lan

Tags: networking

Is there any way that i can track the network usage in my lan. I have assigned fixed ipv4 address to all the machines in my lan. Is it possible to track the data usage for individual machine in router?

Comment: With cheap home routers probably not. With expensive professional grade routers you might be able to.

Comment: What router is it?

Comment: @hertitu its d-link

Comment: Then I refer to Mokubai's and Fana's answers

Answer (score 2):

If you can't change your router, you can monitor the traffic with SNMP & Nagios/Cacti/Centreon/Zabbix/....

First you need to configure your host to enable the SNMP answers.

Here is for [Windows](http://techraze.com/how-to-install-enable-microsoft-snmp-service-in-windows-7-8-8-1) and for [Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/SNMP).

Once this is done, you need to install the monitoring software of your choice.

Here's the documentation for [Cacti](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/cacti.htm).

Configuring the monitoring software is the hardest part ... But that could be the subject of another question.